# Have a doubt about few concepts - Can anyone elaborate it

Tags: rectangles

For a given perimeter, the rectangle with the largest area is a square.
For a given area, the rectangle with the smallest perimeter is a square.
What do the above sentences mean?
Can any one explain the concepts with examples?

Comment: Think about the inequality $ab \leq \left( \frac{a+b}{2} \right)^2$.

Comment: For a given area the rectangle with the smallest perimeter is a square.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the perimeter is $24$.

The rectangle could be $1\times 11$ with area $11$ or $4\times 8$ with area $32$ but the greatest area is $6\times 6=36$.

Suppose the area is $36$.

The perimeter could be $74$ with sides $36\times 1$ or $30$ with sides $3\times 12$. But the smallest perimeter would be $24$ for a square of side $6$.